# JavaFX generating UI controlls from backend classes

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, layers

I have a problem with my Software design. I want to generate UI controls from XML messages over the network. The XML messages contain simple information about a component and its properties for example:

```
<? version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<components>
    <component name="Car">
        <property name="length" type="double" value="4.1"/>
        <property name="numSeatbelts" type="int" value="5"/>
        ...
        ...
    </component>
    ...
    ...
</components>
```

The goal is to create UI elements dynamically that represent these properties and enable modification.
The properties are loaded into instances of the Property class that resides in my backend:

```
public class Property<T> {
    String getName();
    T getValue();
    void setValue(T value);
}
```

The problem now is when I get a List of Properties for panel generation I have no information about the panel type.
My current approach is:

```
void generatePanels(List<Property> properties) {
    for(Property property : properties) {
        if(property.getValue() instanceof Double) {
            add(new DoublePropertyPanel(property));
        } else if(property.getValue() instanceof Integer) {
            add(new IntegerPropertyPanel(property));
        } else if(...) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Which I find really ugly. Is there a way to replace the type checking by a OOP pattern, while preserving layer separation (Properties should not know of the existence of the UI)?

Here is a **extremely simplified** diagram of my program:

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't store the type you get in the message as well as the name and value? You do have it when you create the Properties entry? Then I would also create an Enum to map all the known values to a  Panel types, with a default (unknown type) set to StringPropertyPanel.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already redesigned my architecture completely to make better use of [JavaFX Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/Property.html) and the [ControlsFX PropertySheet](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/PropertySheet.html). Which has a complete different approach with way less overhead.